# Using Managed Identity to call APIM endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to make a call to the APIM endpoint in Azure from the function app using the Managed Identity of the function app. Not sure if there is any article I could take a reference from?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Trying to do this exact thing and it does not seem possible, can only validate jwt or cert from requests coming in on APIM, but cannot make use of managed identity to simplify the process.

Comment: I used the default credential of function app to get the token and passed that token as Authorization Header. We'll need to provide applicationId while trying to get a token, currently a new app registration is being used for this.  How are you using certificate to make https call? Are you uploading it in TLS/SSL settings public cert and using it in your code? If so, are you using linux/windows os?

Comment: At this point most of our incoming requests come from other sources, so they have to pass us a cert that we can just verify using policies and referencing the cert in our keyvault. We wanted to ease the process of making calls from our system to external systems without having to write code to get a token using an app registration, but it seems like that is the only way currently. We make use of linux and windows based apps

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it using validate-jwt policy. The policy will look like this:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="aud">
            <value>{backend-api-application-client-id}</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this policy type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ManagedIdentity